# 2000 Ford Focus zetec no idle after engine mount failure

Tags: engine, ford, focus, idle, zetec

I’ve been working on a friends 2000 Ford Focus/Zetec engine, he had his motor mount fail on him while driving which he fortunately stopped driving, after inspection I noticed that the engine had dropped down and forward. I got the new mount installed and the engine is now back in its proper position, but now the car doesn’t idle at all and it needs the gas pedal to be feathered in order to run at all, and also shakes while being revved, I’m thinking that the connection to the idle control valve has been unhooked from the engine movement, as I have inspected all other parts hoses that pertain to the no idle problem? As well the car idled perfect before the engine mount failed and the engine dropped? Codes p1131 and p0443 come up on the scanner.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Are there any codes present? If so, what are they?

Comment: Check the air intake pipes from from the airbox to the engine.  The airbox looks like it is fastened to the body, so the pipe may have been damaged and may be letting unmetered air in.

Comment: There could be a ground strap or cable that was torn or just not re-connected. Sometimes the ground strap is located at a motor mount. The strap provides a solid ground connection between the engine and the frame/body.